# WKWebView crash on iOS 15 running in simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, wkwebview

WKWebView crashes on iOS 15 running in simulator on load method.

> exc_bad_access (code=1 address=0x10)

On iOS 14 WKWebView works fine. How to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Workaround**: Deselecting “Enable backtrace recording.” option in scheme.

In Xcode, select Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme, Run > Options > Queue Debugging > Deselect “Enable backtrace recording.”